# Implementing **<class>?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, overloading, magic-methods

**Edit**:

This question has been marked duplicate but I don't think that it is. Implementing the suggested answer, that is to use the Mapping abc, does not have the behavior I would like:

```
from collections import Mapping

  class data(Mapping):

    def __init__(self,params):
      self.params = params

    def __getitem__(self,k):
      print "getting",k
      return self.params[k]

    def __len__(self):
      return len(self.params)

    def __iter__(self):
      return ( k for k in self.params.keys() )

def func(*args,**kwargs):
  print "In func"
  return None

ps = data({"p1":1.,"p2":2.})

print "\ncalling...."
func(ps)

print "\ncalling...."
func(**ps)
```

Output:

```
calling....
In func

calling....
in __getitem__ p2
in __getitem__ p1
In func
```

Which, as mentioned in the question, is not what I want.

The other solution, given in the comments, is to modify the routines that are causing problems. That will certainly work, however I was looking for a quick (lazy?) fix!

**Question:**

How can I implement the `**` operator for a class, other than via `__getitem__`? For example I would like to be able to do this::

```
  def func(**kwargs):
    <do some clever stuff>

  x = some_generic_class():

  func( **x )
```

without an implicit call to `some_generic_class.__getitem__()`. In my application I have already implemented `__getitem__` with some data logging which I do not want to perform when the class is referenced as above.

If it's not possible to overload the `**` operator, is it possible to detect when `__getitem__`  is being called as a result of the class being passed to a function, rather than explicitly?

**Background:**

I am working on a physics model that is built out of a set of packages which are chosen according to user input at runtime. The flexible structure of the model means that I rarely know the required parameters and so i pass a `dict` of parameter names and values between the models. In order to make this more user friendly I am now trying to develop a class `paramlist` that overloads the `dict` functionality with a set of routines that do some consistency checking, set default values, etc. The idea is that I pass an instance of `paramlist` rather than a dict. One of the more important aims is to keep a log of which members of `paramlist` have been referenced by the physics packages and which ones have not. A stripped out version is below, which aims to maintain a second `dict` that logs whether a parameter has been referenced::

```
class paramlist(object):

  def __init__( self, params ):

    self.params = copy(params)
    self.used = { k:False for k in self.params }

  def __getitem__(self, k):

    try:
      v = self.params[k]
    except KeyError:
      raise KeyError("Parameter {}  not in parameter list".format(k))
    else:
      self.used[k] = True

    return v

  def __setitem__(self,k,v):
    self.params[k] = v
    self.used[k] = False
```

Which does not have the behaviour I want:

```
  ps = paramlist( {"p1":1.} )

  def donothing( *args, **kwargs ):
    return None

  donothing(ps)
  print paramlist.used["p1"]

  donothing(**ps)
  print paramlist.used["p1"]
```

Output:

```
 False
 True
```

I would like the `use` dict to remain False in both cases, so that I can tell the user that one of their parameters was not used (implying that they screwed up and a default value has been used instead). I presume that the `**` case has the effect of calling `__getitem__` on every entry in the `paramlist`.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need to do is rewrite your functions to take a `paramlist` as a normal argument instead of slurping keyword arguments with `**`.

Comment: If you want, you can keep the `**` versions and have them be simple wrappers around the new versions.

Comment: Thanks guys, this looks good. Sorry for the duplicate - should have thought of searching "double star" rather than "**"